# MyISAM é o storage engine por defeito neste MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, engine

Vi hoje essa mensagem:

> MyIsam é o *storage engine* por defeito neste MySQL *server*

Como assim "*por defeito*"? Que defeito é esse? Eu uso o InnoDB, e mesmo assim aparece essa mensagem.

Existe algum problema em deixar assim? Até agora não ocorreu nenhum, mas existe?

Como eu posso corrigir isso para InnoDB?

Nota: Uso o phpMyAdmin 4.6.4 local, com MySQL 5.7.14.

[image: phpMyAdmin]

Comment: https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/617/121

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Comment: No meu caso é ao contrario "InnoDB é o storage engine por defeito neste MySQL server"... essa postagem me ajudou!

Answer (score 3):

Isto é português de Portugal. Por defeito seria por *default*, ou por padrão como costumamos usar no Brasil. É o valor que será usado na falta de um determinado valor explicitamente no momento que ele será usado.

Então se é o MyISAM na maioria dos casos que deseja usar é o mais correto. Se quase sempre quer usar o InnoDB então seria interessante mudar, mas não é obrigatório porque sempre pode definir o tipo no momento da criação.

Na verdade o mais adequado é criar novos bancos de dados definidos com o *engine* que deseja usar explicitamente para evitar inconvenientes de ter mudado o padrão sem querer ou estar em um ambiente diferente.

Se quiser mudar vá no arquivo `my.cfg` e mude:

```
[mysqld]
default-storage-engine = innodb
```